# Why is the minus sign present in the output?

Tags: datetime, java-8, duration, java-time, timezone-offset

I have the following lines of code:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 06, 02, 6, 0, 0);
ZoneOffset nyOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(-5, 0);        
ZoneId nyZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
OffsetDateTime nyOdt = ldt.atOffset(nyOffset);
ZonedDateTime nyZdt = ldt.atZone(nyZone);
Duration d = Duration.between(nyOdt, nyZdt);
System.out.println(d);
```

The output is `PT-1H`. Why is this happening? `nyZdt` is not before `nyOdt`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Because NYC's timezone offset is -4 hours in June.

Comment: New York is only 4 hours behind UTC in June: https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20170602T100000&p1=179&p2=tz_gmt. `ny0dt - nyZdt` = `(-5) - (-4)` = -1.

Comment: Take a look at `nyOffset.getRules().isFixedOffset()` vs `nyZone.getRules().isFixedOffset()`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Fair enough but `nyOdt` is 1AM and `nyZdt` is 2AM.  So `nyZdt` is after `nyOdt`. Why does the minus sign appear?

Comment: `ny0dt` is 6AM in `UTC-4`; `nyZdt` is 6AM in `UTC-5`, which is 5AM in `UTC-4`. 6AM to 5AM is -1 hour.

Comment: @yshavit I understand, this how it works, ny0dt - nyZdt = (-5) - (-4) = -1. We make the difference between those negative values. Make sense. Thank you!

Comment: @IoanaP. You are mistaken. `nyOdt` is 11 AM UTC, and `nyZdt` is 10 AM UTC. The offsets show how much they *have been* offset from UTC, not how much you should offset them to get to UTC. Print them using `toInstant()` to see for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can become more clear if you print the dates and the corresponding UTC `Instant` of both:

```
System.out.println(nyOdt);
System.out.println(nyZdt);
System.out.println(nyOdt.toInstant());
System.out.println(nyZdt.toInstant());
```

This will print:

> 2017-06-02T06:00-05:00
>   2017-06-02T06:00-04:00[America/New_York]
>   2017-06-02T11:00:00Z
>   2017-06-02T10:00:00Z

Notice that `nyOdt` is using offset `-05:00` (5 hours behind UTC), but `nyZdt` is using `-04:00` (4 hours behind UTC, due to [Daylight Saving Time in New York](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/new-york)).

Converting them to `Instant`'s, you can see that `nyOdt` is equivalent to 11 AM in UTC, and `nyZdt` is equivalent to 10 AM in UTC. That's why the difference between both is **minus one hour**: `Duration.between()` returns a negative duration [if the first parameter is after the second](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) (and `nyOdt.toInstant().isAfter(nyZdt.toInstant())` returns `true`).

Comment: Completely understood. Thank you!